# Compiling Linux Buildroot overrides local changes

Tags: linux, buildroot

I am working to enable the kexec support in my propriety Linux distribution and I would like to debug the kexec tools in user space.  I am adding debug prints in the kexec.c that's located in *buildroot/output/build/kexec-2.0.15/kexec/kexec.c*, but if I do an incremental build with `make`, it doesn't look like the kexec binary has been updated.  If I rebuild everything from scratch with `make all`, the source code kexec.c has been overridden and I don't see my changes.  My guess is that every full build re-extracts the kexec package and that is why my changes are not taking affect.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use "make kexec-rebuild".

Answer (score 0):

> If you only want to restart the build process of a package from its
>   compilation step, you can run make `<package>-rebuild` [...]. It will restart the compilation and installation of
>   the package, but not from scratch: it basically re-executes make and
>   make install inside the package, so it will only rebuild files that
>   changed.
>
> [...]
>
> Internally, Buildroot creates so-called stamp files to keep track of
>   which build steps have been completed for each package. They are
>   stored in the package build directory,
>   output/build/-/ and are named .stamp_.
>   The commands detailed above simply manipulate these stamp files to
>   force Buildroot to restart a specific set of steps of a package build
>   process.

(from the Buildroot manual, section [Understanding how to rebuild packages](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rebuild-pkg) -- I suggest you read the whole section)

Also, look at your build log. If you don't see a line like

`>>> kexec 2.0.16 Building`

then the kecxec package hasn't been (re)built.